# Compiling GNU software on HP-UX. yy* symbols problem

Tags: gnu, compilation, hp-ux

When trying to compile GNU software on HP-UX (binutils for example) I'm getting error meggages about unsatisfied symbols yyfnd, yyextra, yytextuc, yyolsp ...

Some software can't be compiled using HP-UX own lex so i've included byacc and flex executables in my PATH. Is it HP-UX lex problem? How to fix it?

Comment: could you post the error messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried building with `-lfl` and/or `-ly`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need the flex function or can you just try export LEXLIB=" " ?